# Creating 16 and 24-bit integers from binary file

Tags: python, binaryfiles

I'm modifying an existing Python app that reads a binary file.  The format of the file is changing a bit.  Currently, one field is defined as bytes 35-36 of the record.  The specs also state that "...fields in the records will be character fields written in ASCII."  Here's what the current working code looks like:

```
def to_i16( word ):
    xx = struct.unpack( '2c', word )
    xx = ( ord( xx[ 0 ] ) << 8 ) + ord( xx[ 1 ] )

    return xx

val = to_i16( reg[ 34:36 ] )
```

But that field is being redefined as a bytes 35-37, so it'll be a 24-bit value.  I detest working with binary files and am horrible at bit-twiddling.  How do I turn that 3-byte value into a 24-bit integer??  I've tried a couple of code bits that I've found by googling but I don't think they are correct.  Hard to be sure since I'm still waiting on the people that sent the sample 'new format' file to send me a text representation that shows the values I should be coming up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply read 24 bit (I assume in [big endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianess), since the original code is in that format as well ):

```
val = struct.unpack('>I', b'\x00' + reg[34:37])
```

Comment: I copied/pasted that and am getting a syntax error.  I'm using Python v2.4, if that matters.

Comment: If I change the `b'\x00'` to just `'\x00'`, it works and produces the same value as `( ord( xx[ 0 ] ) << 16 ) + ( ord( xx[ 1 ] ) << 8 )  + ord( xx[ 2 ] )`.

Comment: @DaveKub Yup, in 2.4, you need to leave out the leading `b`. Note that 2.4 is completely out of date and unsupported though, so you may want to consider updating.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's old.  But it's what's on the server at work and I don't have any control over that, unfortunately.  Thanks!

Comment: For signed values try: `val = struct.unpack('>i', reg[34:37]+'\x00')[0] >> 8`